# Dynamic add directive in controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, controller, directive

I wrote the followings in a controller in angularjs:

```
var firstName = angular.element('<input id="firstName" 
class="w3-input w3-border w3-round" name="firstName" type="text"   
placeholder="Firstname" ng-model="firstName" required is-number-directive>
<span class="w3-red w3-small" ng-show="userForm.firstName.$invalid">Is 
required.</span></p>
<p><label class="w3-text-black w3-left w3-large">LastName</label>');
var firstNameCompile = $compile(firstName)($scope);
```

And the directive is:

```
app.directive('isNumberDirective', function() {
return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, mCtrl) {
        function myValidation(value) {
            var x = +value;               
            if (x.toString() === value) {
                mCtrl.$setValidity('isNumber', true);
            } else {
                mCtrl.$setValidity('isNumber', false);
            }
            return value;
        }
        mCtrl.$parsers.push(myValidation);
    }
};
});
```

When I create & instatiate the firstNameCompile object the directive does not bind to the object. Consider also that the same directive works fine in simple html page where i create the input object.
Any suggetsion? I have to create the object via javascript.

Comment: why are you compiling the html. just add template property in directive and  assign the html to it

Comment: I do it before but the directive's evaluation does not work.In plain html works fine